# PHP Fetching Data From Specific MySQL Row

Tags: php, mysql

Recently I've set it up so I can update my sites news via my administration panel and now I've been seeking across the web for a solution to print specific lines.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM BananzaNews";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BananzaNews", $con);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

The above tells me how many rows I have and for my five most recent which will be shown on my home page, I want to fetch the data for $num_rows, $num_rows -1, $num_rows -2, $num_rows -3 and $num_rows -4.

The data to fetch;

- title
- newsDate
- imagePath
- content
- websitePath

My current dummy filled code is the following dubplicated five times;

```
<div class="Feed">
    <div class="Img"><img alt="" src="http://www.davidreneke.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/News-Briefs.png"></div>
    <div class="Title">My Testing Title</div>
    <div class="Date">
        <div class="Day">22</div>
        <div class="Month">Jan</div>
        <div class="Year">2015</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Brief">Vivamus consectetur et sapien vel rhoncus. Maecenas gravida posuere hendrerit. Duis lobortis justo ac justo malesuada commodo. Proin iaculis, erat ac aliquet eleifend, neque felis tristique turpis, at dictum tellus lectus et lorem. Nunc turpis enim, auctor sed purus nec.</div>
    <div class="More"></div>
    <div class="Divider"></div>
</div>
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php
    $query = 'SELECT title,newsDate,imagePath,content,websitePath FROM BananzaNews ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 5';
    $resultSe = mysql_query($query, $con);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = $resultSet->fetchRow ( DB_FETCHMODE_OBJECT )){
            echo "<div class=\"Feed\">
            <div class=\"Img\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"" $row->imagePath "\"></div>
            <div class=\"Title\">" $row->title "</div>
            <div class=\"Date\">
                <div class=\"Day\">" $row->newsDate "</div>
                <div class=\"Month\">" $row->newsDate "</div>
                <div class=\"Year\">" $row->newsDate "</div>
            </div>
            <div class=\"Brief\">" $row->content "</div>
            <div class=\"More\">" $row->websitePath "</div>
            <div class=\"Divider\"></div>
        </div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Database View
[image]

Comment: `mysql_num_rows()` will only return the number of rows obtained on running the query. Are you fetching the result set from the query anywhere using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`? Also using `mysql_*` leaves your code vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: use mysql_fetch_array() using while loop

Comment: I don't really know how to respond apart from that I am stupid and know next to nothing. I am trying to establish a somewhat basic site for my charity and have just learnt how to submit to the database. I am now trying to discover how to display the last 5 entries on my websites home page.

Comment: `$num_rows -1` ??? what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use MySQL's `ORDER BY`. You don't need to use `num_rows` to get the 5 latest posts. Simply order them by their `id` columns and then `LIMIT` it to 5. If they don't have `id` columns, they should have an id column that `auto_increment`s and is a `PRIMARY KEY`. With that, this code will help you:

```
//Load your mysql_query into a variable SELECTing not *, but only the rows you need.
$query = mysql_query("SELECT title, newsDate, imagePath, content, websitePath FROM BananzaNews ORDER BY newsid DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error()); //<- Error handling.

//This loads up each row into an associative array into the variable $row
//So, $row['title'] will be equal to the 'title' column at that row in your database
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    //Output your repeating code
    //Notice how I've used concat operators (dots) to stop the echo and start it again.
    //I'd recommend looking those up if you haven't.
    echo 
    '<div class="Feed">
        <div class="Img"><img alt="" src="'.$row['imagePath'].'"></div>
        <div class="Title">'.$row['title'].'</div>
        <div class="Date">
            <div class="Day">22</div>
            <div class="Month">Jan</div>
            <div class="Year">2015</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Brief">'.$row['content'].'</div>
        <div class="More"></div>
        <div class="Divider"></div>
    </div>';

}
```

I would actually also use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) over mysql, mainly because it's well... mysql-improved. Do look into it, I highly recommend it. Even better, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: I updated my code with yours but have no result :( . For mysqli do I simply add the 'i' or is there much more too it?

Comment: @TimMarshall, there's more to it, of course. That's why I included the link. Use mysql for now to get the hang of it, and then look into mysqli later. My code should work. Do you get any errors? I just added error handling to the $query, so try it again and let me know what error you get.

Comment: Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'. I've just added my code [here](http://tny.cz/024cc9c3) password: bananza123

Comment: You need to add an id column to your table. It needs to be `NOT NULL auto_increment`, and it needs to be the `PRIMARY KEY`. Let me know if that makes sense and if you need help with that.

Comment: I do have an ID set, please see my edited question, I added an image - Just edited image

Comment: I am feeling so revealed right now I cannot thank you enough!!! However can I be cheeky and ask how I split .$row['newsDate'] up into dd for one section, mm for another and yyy for another?

Comment: [PHP's date_format()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) is your friend.

Comment: My attempt of `'.date_format($row['newsDate'],"yy").'` failed but I'm sure I'll get there. Thank you so very much for the help!

Comment: Got it! -> `'.date("Y", strtotime($row['newsDate'])).'`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the data to fetch run your query in while loop

```
$result=mysqli_query("select * from table_name order by id desc limit 0,5")
while($each=mysqli_fetch_array($result ))

 {
 //your code goes here
 }
```

Comment: Can you please link to some resource as this does not mean much to me, I could get the whole database but I only want the last 5 rows added.

Comment: I was trying to add a comment but the site didn't like what I was saying. Thanks

Comment: Dreamweaver seems to think the following is wrong; `while($each=mysqli_fetch_array($result ))`

Comment: I've got mysqli multiple places but no errors. I have Adobe CC so always have the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query it will work for you

```
$query = 'SELECT title,newsDate,imagePath,content,websitePath FROM BananzaNews ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 5';
$resultSet = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)){
      echo $row['title'];
      echo $row['newsDate'];
    }
}
```

You can loop your data like this.

Comment: How would I loop my html inserting the data? I'm not asking for a snippet, just a show of 'title' or 'date (just day)' if possible?

Comment: I made some changes please check

Comment: Fatal Error: Call To A Member Function NumRows() On A Non-Object

Comment: This because of framework difference. you use mysql_num_rows($result) at the place of $resultSet->numRows ()

Comment: I don't quite understand, I copied what you posted replacing my code.

Comment: because I am using codeigniter framework, and it works with that. you just place mysql_num_rows($result) at the place of $resultSet->numRows () . it will work for you.

Comment: Could you please check my updated question? I cannot get this to work and I am unsure how to split up my date.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

`1.` use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead of `mysql` extension. It already depreciated and will be remove in future.

`2.` `Loop` your `result set` to get all the data from the table.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM BananzaNews LIMIT 0,5");
    $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    ?>
    <table>
    <?php
    do
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $rs['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rs['newsDate']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rs['imagePath']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rs['content']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rs['websitePath']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: I don't see any numbers to indicate only 5 results?

Comment: @TimMarshall, I updated my answer. Please check i hope it will work for you.